# Run time error 91 Object variable or with block variable not set for autofilter function in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I'm turning my head inside out trying to work this out, I have the simplest function and am getting an error

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet

ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.ApplyFilter <---- error line

End Sub

Gives me Run-time error '91': Object variable or with block variable not set
```

Everything seems set to me, so I'm at a loss, what can I set more?

Comment: Perhaps see the Remarks in the [`Worksheet.AutoFilter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.autofilter) documentation.

Comment: Btw, you can probably use `Me` instead of `ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet` - `Me` would refer to the sheet containing the `Worksheet_Change` handler.

Comment: So I changed to Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
Dim wsFilter As AutoFilter
Set wsFilter = ws.AutoFilter
ws.ApplyFilter which still gives me a Method or data member does not exist

Comment: Did you read the remarks in the docs? "To create an AutoFilter object for a worksheet, you must turn autofiltering on for a range on the worksheet either manually or by using the AutoFilter method of the Range object." Did you do that?

Comment: Using `ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.ApplyFilter` makes sense only if a filter has been previously applied and you used `ActiveSheet.ShowAllData`. So you need to previously check `ActiveSheet.FilterMode`, which means that a filter exists. You will not receive an error, if this code line returns `True`, but it will not make sense neither. It is useful only if you use `ActiveSheet.ShowAllData`, then do something with the range in discussion and after that use `ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.ApplyFilter` to reapply the previous (existing) filter...